# Segregating data based on last 3 months and this time last year

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I need to filter out my data into two different index. 
(1) last three months, includes December as current month minus three
(2) current month (December 2019) and current month values from the year before

```
pDate              Name Date    Year    Month
11/17/2019 12:18    A   2019/11 2019    11
12/23/2018 11:52    B   2018/12 2018    12
12/1/2019 11:42     C   2019/12 2019    12
12/10/2018 14:31    D   2018/12 2018    12
12/14/2018 12:42    E   2018/12 2018    12
10/15/2019 15:19    F   2019/10 2019    10
10/23/2019 10:50    G   2019/10 2019    10
12/2/2018 15:14     H   2018/12 2018    12
```

I was able to group them based upon their last 3 months values, relatively quick as:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by="pDate",ascending=True).set_index("pDate").last("3M")
```

How do I get a dataframe which maps December 2019 (current month) and December 2018 only.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is create month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then you can subtract values for past periods filtering by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
$changed sample datetimes
df['pDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pDate'])
df = df.sort_values(by="pDate")
print (df)
                pDate Name     Date  Year  Month
7 2018-12-02 15:14:00    H  2018/12  2018     12
4 2018-12-14 12:42:00    E  2018/12  2018     12
3 2019-10-10 14:31:00    D  2018/12  2018     12
5 2019-10-15 15:19:00    F  2019/10  2019     10
6 2019-10-23 10:50:00    G  2019/10  2019     10
2 2019-11-01 11:42:00    C  2019/12  2019     12
1 2019-12-23 11:52:00    B  2018/12  2018     12
0 2020-01-17 12:18:00    A  2019/11  2019     11

nowp = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m')
print (nowp)
2020-01

df['per'] = df['pDate'].dt.to_period('m')
df = df[df['per'].between(nowp-4, nowp-1) | df['per'].eq(nowp-13)]
print (df)
                pDate Name     Date  Year  Month      per
7 2018-12-02 15:14:00    H  2018/12  2018     12  2018-12
4 2018-12-14 12:42:00    E  2018/12  2018     12  2018-12
3 2019-10-10 14:31:00    D  2018/12  2018     12  2019-10
5 2019-10-15 15:19:00    F  2019/10  2019     10  2019-10
6 2019-10-23 10:50:00    G  2019/10  2019     10  2019-10
2 2019-11-01 11:42:00    C  2019/12  2019     12  2019-11
1 2019-12-23 11:52:00    B  2018/12  2018     12  2019-12
```

**Detail**:

```
print (nowp)
2020-01
print (nowp-1)
2019-12
print (nowp-13)
2018-12
print (nowp-4)
2019-09
```

Comment: Technically, yes! The output is exactly what I want. But is there any way to  dynamically get this content, without passing the actual values directly?

Comment: @PukarAcharya - Sure, but not understand `December 2019 (current month)`, it is not `January 2020` ?

Comment: This data is complied at the end of every month. As January is still running on 13th, so my current data will be till the last day of December. When I run the query next on, say, Feb 1 2020, I should get my data which includes Jan 2020 and Jan 2019. This Dec 2019 and Dec 2018 mapping is likewise. So I am looking out for a dynamic indexing query.

Comment: @PukarAcharya - So is necessary first subtract one month? Can you check edited answer?

Comment: it has 0 data. The timestamp in my dataset are as: `2019-12, 2019-11, 2019-10, 2018-12`. If I run the query next time in Feb, it will be updated to: `2020-01, 2019-12, 2019-11, 2019-01`. `now.year` means the date index comes to 2020.

Comment: Changed the year value to: `agent_data_y = agent_data_y[agent_data_y.index.year.isin([now.year - 1 , now.year - 2]) & (agent_data_y.Month.values == 12)]` 

with this, I will have to update the query almost every month, since currently, now.year will be 2020, but my data ends on 2019-12. Next month, I should be updating the month index to 01, and [now.year-1, now.year-2] will be changed to [now.year, now.year-1]. I was looking out for a query that maps this situation automatically @jezrael

Comment: You df has values from month 10 (2019/10) as well. I need same month values of two consecutive years only, i.e [2019-12 and 2018-12], next will be [2020-01 and 2019-01] @jezrael

Comment: @PukarAcharya - yop, it is `df['per'].eq(nowp-13)`